# Creating a graph from a Field values (VBA ArcObjects)

Tags: arcobjects, vba, statistics

I have a combobox that shows all fields of a shapefile.

I want to get these values programmatically in a label--Count, Minimum, Maximum, Sum, Mean, Standard Deviation--and populate a graph of the selectable fields in the combobox.  All that in the same form.

---

It work Jakub, but sometimes it give an error that close all the ArcGIS opened windows.

I did some changes to the code.
This is my code:

```
Private Sub CmboFld_Change()
  Dim pMxDoc As esriArcMapUI.IMxDocument, pFLayer As esriCarto.IFeatureLayer, pData As esriGeoDatabase.IDataStatistics
  Dim pCursor As esriGeoDatabase.ICursor, pStatResults As esriSystem.IStatisticsResults
  Set pMxDoc = ThisDocument
  Set pFLayer = pMxDoc.FocusMap.Layer(0)
  Set pCursor = pFLayer.Search(Nothing, False)
  
  Set pData = New esriGeoDatabase.DataStatistics
  pData.Field = CmboFld.Text
  Set pData.Cursor = pCursor
  
  Dim pEnumVar As esriSystem.IEnumVariantSimple, value As Variant
  Set pEnumVar = pData.UniqueValues
  value = pEnumVar.Next
  
  Set pCursor = pFLayer.Search(Nothing, False)
  Set pData.Cursor = pCursor
  Set pStatResults = pData.Statistics
  Txt1.Caption = pStatResults.Maximum
  Txt2.Caption = pStatResults.Minimum
  Txt3.Caption = pStatResults.Sum
  Txt4.Caption = pStatResults.Mean
  Txt5.Caption = pStatResults.StandardDeviation
End Sub
```

and :

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
  '------------- Remplir la combobox------------------------------------
  'clear combobox
  CmboFld.Clear
  Dim i As Integer
  Dim pMxDoc As IMxDocument
  Set pMxDoc = ThisDocument
  Dim pFeatureLayer As IFeatureLayer
  Set pFeatureLayer = pMxDoc.FocusMap.Layer(0) '1st layer
  For i = 0 To pFeatureLayer.FeatureClass.Fields.FieldCount - 1
    CmboFld.AddItem pFeatureLayer.FeatureClass.Fields.Field(i).Name
  Next i
End Sub
```

It work, now I have a problem, how to populate a graph, I did used this:

```
Private Sub Graph()
    Dim pMxDoc As IMxDocument
    Set pMxDoc = ThisDocument
    
    ' get the name of the layer containing feature points
    Dim pLayer As ILayer
    Set pLayer = pMxDoc.FocusMap.Layer(0)
    
    ' create graph
    Dim pDataGraphBase As IDataGraphBase
    Dim pDataGraphT As IDataGraphT
    Set pDataGraphBase = New DataGraphT
    Set pDataGraphT = pDataGraphBase
    
    Dim layerName As String
    layerName = pLayer.Name
    
    ' graph and legend titles
    pDataGraphT.GeneralProperties.Title = "Graphe"
    pDataGraphT.LegendProperties.Title = "Legende"
    pDataGraphBase.Name = "Graphe représentant - " & layerName
    
    ' create vertical line series
    Dim pSP As ISeriesProperties
    Set pSP = pDataGraphT.AddSeries("line:vertical")
    pSP.colorType = esriGraphColorMatch
    pSP.WhereClause = "GAGE_NO_ = 2 AND YEAR_ = 99"
    pSP.InLegend = True
    
    pSP.SourceData = pLayer
    pSP.SetField 0, "TSDateTime"
    pSP.SetField 1, "TSValue"
    Dim pSortFlds As IDataSortSeriesProperties
    Set pSortFlds = pSP
    Dim idx As Long
    pSortFlds.AddSortingField "TSDateTime", True, idx
    
    Dim pCancelTracker As ITrackCancel
    Set pCancelTracker = New CancelTracker
    pDataGraphT.Update pCancelTracker
    
    ' create data graph window within ArcMap
    Dim pDGWin As IDataGraphWindow2
    Set pDGWin = New DataGraphWindow
    Set pDGWin.DataGraphBase = pDataGraphBase
    Set pDGWin.Application = ThisDocument.Parent
    pDGWin.Show (True)
    
    Dim pDataGraphs As IDataGraphCollection
    Set pDataGraphs = pMxDoc
    pDataGraphs.AddDataGraph pDataGraphBase
    
        ' export the graph instead of displaying in ArcMap, use the following code,
        ' and comment the above 9 lines
        Dim fileName As String
        fileName = Form1.Dir & layerName & ".jpg"
        pDataGraphT.ExportToFile fileName
End Sub

Private Sub CmdGrph_Click()
    Graph
End Sub
```

It give me an empty graph, with a text zone "There is no selection"
when I double click at that zone text, it give me, graph properties
I choose this information:

**Graph Type:** Vertical Bar

**Layer/Table:** pMxDoc.FocusMap.Layer(0)

**Value Field:** CmboFld.Text

then it populate the graph.

I want to populate that Graph AUTOMATICALLY when I click at Graph Button.

Comment: How will you get these values in a label...can you please explain? Do you want separate labels for each? What about the axis information about the graph...?

Answer (score 1):

iDataStatistics

Example here: http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/ComponentHelp/esriGeoDatabase/IDataStatistics_Example.htm

Comment: thank u for the answer but  it doesn't work

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Can you be more specific? IDataStatistics:Statistics (IStatisticsResults) will provide you with the required field statistics.

Comment: it work,  i re try it it works know, but sometimes it give an error and close all arcgis opened files..

Comment: i did some changes, that's the code i wrote :

Comment: here is the message error :
Erreur d'exécution '-2147417848(80010108)'

Erreur Automation 
L'objet invoqué s'est déconnecté de ses clients